# Variables are not incrementing and unable to sort list

Tags: python, csv, sorting, variables, increment

I have been attempting to make a practice program to score points for correct answers in a quiz.
The score isn't changing or rather holding the values, but resetting to zero.

Additionally, The score table is displaying the list of players from the csv file but not sorted.

I have looked and have tried to use score = score+1 and global score but neither seemed to work.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

````
import csv, operator
import random
from sys import argv
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import islice
count = 0
guess = (" ")
paper = (' ')
username = ' '
x = 0




#username and password validation
def authentication():
    login = False
    global username
    with open('users.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
username = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        for row in reader:
              if row[0]== username and row[1] == password:
                login = True
                break
              else:
                  login = False
    if login == False:
        print("Incorrect. Game over")
        #exit()
    else:
        print("You are logged in. Start the game!")
        
        
authentication()
    
def game():
    global guess
    global paper
    with open('newspapers.csv', 'r') as gfile:
        reader = csv.reader(gfile)
        newspaper = list(reader)
        random_paper = random.choice(newspaper)
#print(random_paper)
  #  for row in reader:
        paper = random_paper[0]
        country = random_paper[1]
        abb = paper.split()
        letters = [word[0] for word in abb]
        print ("".join(letters), ' ', country)
        guess = input("What is the newspaper? ")
        scoring()


def scoring():
    global count
    global guess
    global paper
    x = 0
    score = 0
    count = 0
    while count < 2:
        if guess == paper and count == 0:
            print("Correct!")
            x += 3
            count = 0
            print("Score: ", x)
            game()
        elif guess == paper and count == 1:
            print("Correct!")
            x +=1
            count =0
            print("Score: ", x)
            game()
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            count = count + 1
            guess = input("What is the newspaper? ")
            if count == 2:
                print("Game over")
                break
            else:
                print()
    print("Your score is: ", x)
                

game()

def highscores():
    global username
    global x
    rank = 0
    newrow = (username, x)
    with open('Scores.csv', 'a',newline='') as sfile:
        writer = csv.writer(sfile)
        writer.writerow(newrow)
        

    with open('Scores.csv', 'r') as sfile:
        show_scores = csv.reader(sfile)
        #should sort list but isn't
        sortedList = sorted(show_scores, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        for eachline in islice(sortedList, 1, 6):
            print(eachline)
        


highscores()```
````

Comment: in `scoring()` you probably want `x` to also be global. Your code is a mess though, you should really look into how to pass variables around and then into what classes are

Comment: I would have made the exact opposite recommendation: remove all global variables, and use function parameters as well as keyword `return` to pass the variables.

Comment: None of your function use keyword `return`. That's very suspicious. In general, keyword `global` introduces more problems than it solves, unless you really really know what you're doing. If you're a beginner, I recommend avoiding `global` entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I am still somewhat a beginner.  I have wanted to break up a really long program using more than one function or procedure and so I clearly am having issues calling variables into other programs. I knew how to create a global variable, but have not used return before today. What should the function with the variable parameters look like as an example?  And what is wrong with my code when trying to sort the results? I know it's not efficient or neat. I was following a tutorial from: "https://www.vivaxsolutions.com/web/python.aspx#cons" to develop my basic skills.